# Image of group homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Consider the subgroup $\mathbb{U}_{100}$ of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{C}^\times$ consisting of all the 100-th roots of unity. Define a group homomorphism as:
$$
f:\mathbb{U}_{100}\to\mathbb{U}_{100},\space\space\space\space z\mapsto z^{70}
$$

What is the order of the image of $f$?

I know that the image of $f$ is a set of the elements $\mathbb{U}_{100}$ such that the set is an image under $f$ but I'm not quite sure what to do...

Comment: Did you try to write an expression of an arbitrary element of $\mathbb U_{100}$ and plug that into the formula? If so, what happened?

Comment: Have you tried seing what happens if you replace 70 with 7? How about replacing 70 with 10?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The order of the image of a group homomorphism

is the order of the group divided by the order of the kernel.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609613/order-of-a-group-order-of-kernel-%C3%97-order-of-homomorphic-image)

Answer (score 1):

The elements of $\mathbb U_{100}$ are $u^k$ where $u$ is the first $100$th root of unity.
$$(u^k)^{70}=(u^{10})^{7k}$$
and $u^{10}$ is the first tenth root of unity. Powering this by any exponent will only give other tenth roots of unity, so the image of $f$ has order $10$. (Note that $7$ is coprime to $10$.)

Comment: Thanks! So if, for example, we had $z^{15}$ would it be $(u^k)^{15}=(u^{15})^k$ hence the order is $15$?

Comment: @butterchi $z^{15}$ would give an order of $20$, since $(u^k)^{15}=(u^5)^{3k}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

We see that
$$
f(\mathbb{U}_{100})=\{ z^{70} | z \in \mathbb{U}_{100} \}=\{ e^{ik\pi\frac{7}{5}} | k \in [0,99]\}=\left < e^{i\pi\frac{7}{5}}\right>.
$$
We see that $o \mid 10$ where $o$ is the order of $f(\mathbb{U}_{100})$. So $o \in \{1,2,5,10\}$. You can try each case and see that $o=10$.

Answer (score 0):

In any group we have $\langle g^k \rangle = \langle g^d \rangle$ for $d=\gcd(k,n)$.
One inclusion is obvious. The other follows from [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Let $g$ be a primitive $100$th root of unity. Then $\mathbb{U}_{100} = \langle g \rangle$ and so the image of $f$ is $\langle g^{70} \rangle = \langle g^{10} \rangle$ since $10=\gcd(70,100)$.
The order of $g^{10}$ is $100/10=10$ and so the image has order $10$.

Comment: Adapted from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2216035/589